# web request error - target principal name is incorrect

Tags: c#, rest, dynamic, dynamics-crm

I am trying to send a webrequest to our crm. 
When I access the URL with my browser all is working fine and I get a response.
But with my c# request, I am getting the following error.

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. The target
>   principal name is incorrect.

the code looks like this

```
String url = @"http://localhost/CRMOrga";
String parameters = @"/api/data/v8.2/contacts?$select=lastname,e_mail&$filter=lastname eq 'TEST'";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + parameters);

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"DOMAIN\USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    String responseValue = string.Empty;

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
        throw new ApplicationException(message);
    }

    // grab the response
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream != null)
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
    }
    return responseValue;
}
```

Comment: 401 -> UNAUTHORIZED. Verify that provided credentials are valid.

Comment: sure, the credentials are right - I doublechecked this

Comment: I also tried new NetworkCredential(@"USERNAME", "PASSWORD" , "DOMAIN"), same error

Comment: If you use Fiddler or similar web debugging proxy to examine the differences between your request and the browser's - do you see any significant difference? Can you get the source code of the destination service that is issuing the 401 response, and deduce what is wrong from that end? (it says localhost so i presume you have the source code in another VS project, running in a local IIS/local dev webserver and can debug it)

Comment: Its the same error in the application ( I used the CRM DiagTool to trace it ). 
I can not look into the sourcecode of the service - the receiver is the microsoft crm rest api. 
Localhost is working, because I am debugging my application with the request on the same server as the crm is, to prevent routing errors etc.

Comment: Try ip or server name instead of localhost & see.. sounds to me more of a DC hookup issue..

Comment: i tried both, servername ( and DNS name ) and the IP - same effect